# .txt file - how to know if file has been changed?

Tags: txt

I have a .txt file and I have to know if it was changed... Txt file is some conversation between my customer and my colleague. Is it hack conversation from him because he delete it and he say "i will show you the true" The colleague isnt fair I think he changed this chat.. Can somebody help? Thank you.

I didnt try anything

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], your question doesn't seem to be about programming at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't have a backup then you can see the modified date in windows (if you have other OS you will also find these options in file explorer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).